# Update dict without adding new keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

What is a good 1-liner (other than putting this into a function) to achieve this:

```
# like dict1.update(dict2) but does not add any keys from dict2
# that are not already in dict1
for k in dict1:
    if k in dict2:
        dict1[k]=dict2[k]
```

I guess that this would work, but uses a "protected" function:

```
[dict1.__setitem__(k, dict2[k]) for k in dict1 if k in dict2]
```

Comment: It strikes me as inefficient, but you could go `[dict1.update({k: dict2[k]})...` instead of using `__setitem__`.

Comment: `__setitem__()` is not so much 'protected' as that it's an internal API hook implementation. You normally would use the API directly, calling `dict1[k] = dict2[k]` or you'd use `operator.setitem(dict1, k, dict2[k])` instead. Not necessary here, but that's what you'd use instead of calling `__setitem__()` directly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in set(dict2).intersection(dict1))
```

is how I'd do it in Python 2.6 or below (see further on how to do this in later versions).

Next to another mapping, [`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) can also take an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples, which we generate based on the set intersection of the two dictionaries (so all keys they have in common).

Demo:

```
>>> dict1 = {'foo':'bar', 'ham': 'eggs'}
>>> dict2 = {'ham': 'spam', 'bar': 'baz'}
>>> dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in set(dict2).intersection(dict1))
>>> dict1
{'foo': 'bar', 'ham': 'spam'}
```

In python 2.7 you can use the new [Dict views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to achieve the same without casting to sets:

```
dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys())
```

In Python 3, dict views are the default, so you can instead spell this as:

```
dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys())
```

Comment: `dict1.update(pair for pair in dict2.items() if pair[0] in dict1.keys())` would be another way to write @martijn's excellent solution :d

Comment: I would put parens `()` around `dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()` for improved readability.

Answer (score 4):

Non-destructively:

```
dict((k, dict2.get(k, v)) for k, v in dict1.items())
```

Modifying `dict1`:

```
dict1.update((k, v) for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1)
```

Comment: For the non-destructive version only, I would use a dictionary comprehension: `{k: dict2.get(k, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}`.

Comment: The modify version could also use dict comprehension: `dict1.update({k: v: for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1})`. Not sure which one `dict` handles more efficiently in its constructor, an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples or another dict.

Answer (score 1):

Using map/zip
As two lines for readability:

```
match_keys = dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
dict2.update(**dict(zip(match_keys, map(dict2.get, match_keys))))
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
dict2.update(**dict(zip(dict1.keys() & dict2.keys(), map(dict2.get, dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()))))
```

non-destrctively:

```
new_dict = {**dict2, **dict(zip(dict1.keys() & dict2.keys(), map(dict2.get, dict1.keys() & dict2.keys())))}
```