# Merge a dict into another with common fields only

Tags: python, python-3.9

Let's say:

```py
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
b = {'b': 22, 'c': 3}
```

How can I merge `b` into `a`, setting only those attributes that already exist in `a`, ignoring all the other?

Here's the solution I came up with:

```py
a |= {k: v for k, v in b.items() if k in a.keys()}
{'a': 1, 'b': 22}
```

But I'm not sure how pythonic this is. It feels a bit too verbose for such "simple" operation and likely to exist a better solution.
I'm mostly concerned about Python >= 3.9.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Pythonic, but you could look into `set` operations like [set.intersection](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection):

```py
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
b = {'b': 22, 'c': 3}

for common_key in set(a).intersection(b):
    a[common_key] = b[common_key]

print(a)
```

If you want a *Pythonic one-liner*, you could use a `dict` comprehension similar to how you were also:

```py
a = {k : v for k, v in (a | b).items() if k in a}
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 22}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution regarding to this post: [Update dict without adding new keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941115/update-dict-without-adding-new-keys)

```
a.update((k, b[k]) for k in set(b).intersection(a))
```

Output of a:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 22}
```

Comment: There is no reason to copy and paste from other questions. If the other question answers this one, it should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Mark So if I want to help the OP, what to do next time? Only send the link as a comment? Can't close a question by myself

Comment: Comment is the way to go. The comment will help the OP and people who will vote to close the dupe. It will also help keep SO free(er) from duplicate content.